# SPI Programming

Tags: spi, programming, isp

I am trying to program the processor, eventually i connected NOR and Processor in the same line without any isolation. Now i need to program the Flash without interfacing the processor.

Anyone please help to program the FLASH.

Regards,
Ashwin S

[image]

Comment: What processor?

Comment: I am using BCM5334X

Comment: Have you contacted the manufacturer of the NAND device? You should explain that you’re using their device and you wish to have guidance on flashing memory contents via SPI from the host. Though if you’re doing this as a hobby, they probably won’t bother to help you. Regardless, I think you should refer to a datasheet on how you can achieve write access.

Comment: Typically you *pre-program* the flash with a bootloader having a provision to load a firmware or a newer bootloader through some communication interface which the SoC will then write to the flash.  Or you use some interface-based boot mode of the SoC to get an initial bootloader in there, in desperation possibly even JTAG.  Sometimes you can get an SoC to relinquish the SPI by holding it in reset, but on some chips you cannot.   **Likely whatever software stack you intend to run on this already has a usual mode of getting the initial copy on there, you need to research that.**

Comment: It seems very unlikely that you *successfully* placed parts with the support requirements of that SoC on a board yourself without already knowing something about the answer to this question.  So probably, you are using a premade product or EVB.  Therefore, what you need to do is read the manual.

Comment: The trick is to provide the isolation before the PCB is manufactured. Failing that, read the processor's manual for ways of keeping it inactive (tristated) with the board powered up. Like, read very carefully what the I/O pins do while held in reset. Failing THAT : provide temporary isolation now. That typically involves a scalpel now, and a soldering iron later.